# How to check if a new external hard drive has a bad block with free apps?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk

I bought a new 4TB hard drive and will use it as an external hard drive for storage via USB3.0 port.

Before putting any data in it, I would like to check if there is a bad block or not. But so far, I couldn't find a way by googling.

Are there any free tools to achieve what I want? I don't plan to use any paid product. If there is no way to achieve this in MacOS, I will have to use Linux then.

Btw, SMART is NOT supported with the external enclosure and SMART tool can not be used to check all blocks either.

Comment: You may need a kernel extension for S.M.A.R.T compatibility, but deprecated kexts get increasingly more difficult to handle in modern operating systems: https://github.com/kasbert/OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver

Comment: @Redarm yeah, I found that kernel extension, but that project hasn't been updated within 5 years. I don't plan to install a kernel extension which is NOT really maintained. I think I will just run Linux for this purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Even if the kext is maintained, Apple has all but killed them off in Big Sur and above.  They are to be replaced by system extensions: https://developer.apple.com/support/kernel-extensions/

Comment: By the way, binary fruit has released the SATSMART driver for Apple Silicon this year, which can be downloaded separately.  https://binaryfruit.com/category/blog/sat-smart-driver

Answer (score 1):

Bad blocks are re-mapped live by the drive's internal firmware whenever they are found.

There is no need to specifically try to find them all in one go. The manufacturers will have done that before shipping.

One sign of a failing drive is a rapidly-increasing number of bad blocks found in a short time. Only SMART can analyse that, because it keeps historical records.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I knew the manufacturers would do test before shipping. But what about violent delivery service? What if the hard drive has some damage during the shipment? I lost some important data in the past with hard drive. So I would like to make sure it's perfect and no bad sectors before putting any data in it. Btw, I know I always should do backups on important data. Regarding the SMART, it shows it's not supported. So I can not use `smartctl` etc..

Comment: No drive should be the only repository of any information. It's just not worth the risk. if the drive turns out to be a lemon, send it back. Otherwise just use it. There really is no point in writing & reading every single block in one marathon event. The drive is perfectly capable of dealing with them as they arise.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for the info. I figure out I can run smart tests on this enclosure in Linux. Somehow, MacOS does NOT support SMART on external drive. Maybe I just run smart tests on this new harddrive to check its health.

Comment: One more question: should I run extended smart self-test on a new hard drive? I think it will take about 7 hours. Based on your suggestion, there is no need to check bad blocks manually on a new drive.

Comment: tbh, I only ever look at smart data if I suspect something might be going wrong somewhere. Though I've lost a few drives over the years [all backed up, of course], mainly they just become 'too small' so I swap them up for newer, bigger ones. At a vague guess, of the maybe 30 drives I've been through in the past decade on all the machines here, I only lost two or three, the rest just got retired.

Comment: FYI, smartmontools is available for macOS on both Macports and Homebrew.

Comment: @JamesBrickley yeah, I knew smartmontools in MacOS. But as what I mentioned in the question. SMART is NOT supported with the external drive enclosure in MacOS. There was a kernel extension for SMART support on external drive, but it's NOT maintained and last update was 5 years ago. So I have to run Linux for this.